# Issues with a Node app deployed through elastic beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm deploying a node app to an ec2 instance through aws elastic beanstalk. I set up a cron job with the cron node package that, on tick, will run a sequelize query, parse the data returned, then send it in the body of an email.

When testing locally, it works fine and the email gets sent. When i deploy it using awsebcli command `eb deploy`, it says the deploy was successful, but I don't receive any emails.

At first I believed the `npm start` command wasn't working on the server, but I checked the error logs and it appears sequelize is throwing a time out error when trying to connect.

I wrote a configuration for sequelize to connect to multiple schemas at once. Three of those schemas are hosted on the same RDS, one on a seperate RDS.

I've done almost the exact same thing with another node app and it worked fine. The only thing different is the additional schema on a seperate RDS that I'm connecting to fine on my local machine.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be appreciated.

EDIT: Checked server logs and found Sequelize connection error.

Comment: Are there any errors in the server logs?

Comment: @MarkB pulled the last 100 lines and saw this one come up a few times.
`Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionError: connect ETIMEDOUT`

Which obviously implies sequelize isn't able to make a connection to my dbs, but why?

Comment: There's no way to answer your question with the information given. Perhaps check your security groups.

Comment: Given your last comment, that you have since deleted for some reason, it sounds like you need to just update the security group of the separate RDS instance to allow access from the EC2 instances.

Comment: Well I wanted to leave it open for an answer, and my previous comment pretty much gave the answer, so I figured I'd just edit the question and remove the comment. But yes, that would be the only real solution, short of migrating the schema over to the RDS that's already allowing that instance access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that the issue was caused by security groups on aws preventing my instance from connecting to one of the DBs it needed.

**Edit:**

Specifics have been requested. Since this is a very old post and I don't have access to AWS anymore, I can venture a guess on what I did.

If my memory serves correct, the db I was blocked by was hosted in a different aws account. Changing the security group on the DB was not an option as security on that account was firmly maintained. The reason I was able to connect locally was because the facility I was working at had a whitelisted IP on the DB security groups. I eventually settled on running the script on my local machine, since my machine rarely left that location and it did not matter where the script was run, just that it ran periodically. Ideally though, I would have been able to change the security group on the db to allow incoming traffic from my server.

Comment: Please provide more specific details as to how you resolved the issue.

Comment: This is a very old question and I no longer have access to these AWS services, but if you insist... @NickYoung